Google Cloud REST API for Artifact Registry - URL is 404
I want to list all docker images of my artifact registry in Google Cloud Platform.
Therefore I access the REST API.
Following this documentation: https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.repositories.dockerImages/list
curl -X GET --location "https://artifactregistry.googleapis.com/v1/my-project-id/europe-west3/eu.gcr.io/dockerImages?key=AIzaSyBDf2452534f7Y5PfKRjsdgs%12342432TIGrI" --http1.1 \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer ya29.aFGDggsGSDGSHG4253h2ATzmAsT8dYhWoGm7dG1n7Cj-YYgfk-VIV9e-m22gDQnJ-5X7zSB2dgqyj2_T4ZL6yjaDAb8YWCFpKh64UZ-lYjVj1MYnATA7ZiR7AqTPGvL4NbH-MG2q48Fg_NtesOrC4rOHoSyRMrYxFQyuYg4MIXFfsdf23513JSSDGSDASDASDGYSDGw0177" \
    -H "Accept: application/json"

Response is:
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Tue, 09 Apr 2024 09:28:17 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Server: ESF
Content-Length: 1659
X-XSS-Protection: 0
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Alt-Svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000

The "Try this method" feature in the documentation gives me errors as well

Quite confusing since I am sure I match the regex pattern they require:
/^projects\/[^/]+\/locations\/[^/]+\/repositories\/[^/]+$/

Any idea what I am doing wrong? I think I mix up things with the resource parameter somehow but I can't find any example for this request that leads me to the correct usage.

I am looking forward to your feedback to understand whether the provided resolution has helped you in resolving the issue. If not, I am happy to assist further.

I just realized that I was missing the project path segment -> /project/[project-id]. I thought the documentation was having project as a placeholder for the actual project-id.

This may cause, when the client specifies an Accept header when querying for the image manifest and that header does not include the format that the image has, Artifact registry responds with 404 Not Found status and provides an error.
Artifact registry supports multiple image formats, but client may only support some subset of that. Client should send supported format in Accept header and if it is different from the actual Content-Type of the image then it gets the 404 Not Found error which is interpreted as missing image.
You can check the format of the image stored in AR using command like:
curl -s -D - -o /dev/null '
-H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" \
https://[Region]-docker.pkg.dev/v2/[Project]/[Repository]/[Image]/manifests/latest

Fix: Upload image in format supported by the client. You can convert image formats using skopeo copy command:
skopeo copy -f v2s2 docker://[Region]-docker.pkg.dev/[Project]//:latest docker://-docker.pkg.dev/[Repository]/[Image]/:latest docker://[Region]-docker.pkg.dev/[Project]/[Repository]/[Image]:[Tag2]

Also have a look at this Documentation and Stackoverflow Link.
